# DropdownButton error: The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I started seeing this error in my `DropdownButton` after migrating to null safety.

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: myValue,
  onChanged: (String string) { // Error
    print(string);
  },
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: 'foo',
      child: Text('Foo'),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: 'bar',
      child: Text('Bar'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Error:

> The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the implementation of `value` property, it is nullable.

```dart
final T? value;
```

That means you can provide `String?` to the `value` and if you're providing `String?` should the `onChanged` not return `String?`.

To answer your question:

Change the type of `onChanged` method from `String` to `String?` like this:

```dart
onChanged: (String? string) { 
  print(string);
}
```

or, just omit the type `String?` and let Dart infer it for you.

```dart
onChanged: (string) { 
  print(string);
}
```